# Are praying and listening to stories supposed to make dwarf non-idle?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I use the idle count to check if I need to re-assign some dwarfs to a intensive task that is currently on the queue, but that number lately is <10 so I was presuming that my dwarfs are all being productive... nope, they aren't. I counted 24 of my dwarves listening the amazing tale of how a dwarf ceased being the manager of some fort. Apparently it was interesting. Anyhow, are dwarf listening histories and the like supposed to be counted as non-idle?

Comment: Thought the new bits/activities added this last release were supposed to fall under the same logic as breaks or parties.  So, yeah, not idle, but wasting time, in the usual fashion.  Not actually played this release yet though, so not certain.

Comment: Looks like it might be bugged as there's two worship jobs. 'Worship' which actually reduces the need for worshipping, and 'Worship!' which doesn't work correctly and so the dwarfs are never satisfied. Source: http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=154219.0 - Basically if they're stuck with the second one, the dwarfs will never finish. Otherwise worshipping will be a quick task like having a drink or eating I'd presume.

Comment: @djsmiley2k interesting. I saw a few of them also "Listen story!", but since the story teller ended they stopped doing it. Through, then they moved to "Socialize!".

Comment: Yup, some 'event!' items split into multiple branches appently, and this is what's breaking. The 'Praying' job doesn't do this (and maybe Listen Story!' too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the idle counter is meant to show you how many dwarves are sitting around waiting to do something. The new "jobs" like listenting to stories are essentially the new way that dwarves sit around and socialize so the idle counter has become less reliable than it used to be because of how much more common socializing is. My guess is that toady will eventually change it to include socializing dwarves to be a better measure of how many dwarves are working.